Using CXF 3.5.9, how can I force changing soap body tag "ns2" in soap response
this is my request:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:acc="http://www.example.com/service/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <acc:authRequest login="test@example.com" password="somepassworde"/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

this the response:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns2:authResponse status="fail" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/service/">
         <errorMessage>user not found</errorMessage>
      </a:authResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

what i need is to force using tag "<a:" insteade of "<ns2:" in my response,
I have tried to create an interceptor but in vain.
what i need as response is:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <a:authResponse status="fail" xmlns:a="http://www.example.com/service/">
         <errorMessage>user not found</errorMessage>
      </a:authResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>


Why? The prefix shouldn't matter unless there is something weird downstream with processing the xml.

I have several applications that interact with LDAP and I don't know if it will really break something at the level of these apps or not, I will just keep the old behavior with the old version of CXF which responds with <a: instead of <ns2:, just for more safety.

It shouldn't break anything that is the whole point of namespaces.

The response is using a different namespace to open and to close. Copy and paste error?

It shouldn't break anything if the consumer of that response uses a proper XML parser.
